# Blocking access to the admin panel via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, web, admin, cpanel

How can I block all IP addresses for accessing the admin panel of my site and make my PC the only device that can access the site. I used this code:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from ***public_IP***
```

but it would allow all the IP addresses within the network. I was figuring out how to block ALL including addresses within the network. One problem I encounter is that the addresses are dynamic. As I search google, people are saying that the code above is cannot be used to dynamic IP's.

What can you suggest?

Comment: block it via the requested url (filter it to a php script described https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/can-you-restrict-access-using-htaccess-based-on-session-variable-values/2217 here)

Answer (score 0):

Connect via a VPN and Whitelist the VPN IP only instead. 
If you want privacy, you will have to set up a network which only have you in it.